# MassTransit: Initialize consumer constructor with IRequestClient

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, console-application, masstransit

1) Hi. I'm learning MassTransit with RabbitMQ, but stuck with using Request/Respond. I read a lot of articles and try to write console app using MassTransit documentation. But still can't find any information about initializing consumer with IRequestClient interface. Here is My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
        var serviceAddress = new Uri("loopback://localhost/notification.service");
        var requestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);

        var bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
        {
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.NotificationServiceQueue, e =>
            {
                e.Consumer(() => new OrderRegisteredConsumer(???));
            });
        });

        IRequestClient<ISimpleRequest, ISimpleResponse> client = new MessageRequestClient<ISimpleRequest, ISimpleResponse>(bus, serviceAddress, requestTimeout);


        bus.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Listening for Order registered events.. Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

        bus.Stop();
    }
```

And my consumer

```
public class OrderRegisteredConsumer: IConsumer<IOrderRegisteredEvent>
{
    private static IBusControl _bus;

    IRequestClient<ISimpleRequest, ISimpleResponse> _client;

    public OrderRegisteredConsumer(IRequestClient<ISimpleRequest, ISimpleResponse> client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IOrderRegisteredEvent> context)
    {

        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Customer notification sent: Order id {context.Message.OrderId}");

            ISimpleResponse response = await _client.Request(new SimpleRequest(context.Message.OrderId.ToString()));

            Console.WriteLine("Customer Name: {0}", response.CustomerName); 

    }
}
```

How can I put my client inside

```
e.Consumer(() => new OrderRegisteredConsumer(???));
```

2) I Also try to find some information about Request/Respond in sagas, but, unfortunately, all I find is https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/664

I will appreciate If someone have an example of using this in sagas, or if someone could provide some links, where I can read about this more.

Comment: Request from state machine: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/MassTransit.AutomatonymousIntegration.Tests/Request_Specs.cs#L27

Answer (score 4):

You need the client variable to be available, but the client doesn't need to be ready at the moment you configure the endpoint. `endpoint.Consumer` does not instantiate the consumer straight away, it just needs a factory delegate, which will instantiate the consumer when a message comes for this consumer.

Since the delegate is a reference type, you can assign it later in your code.

So this would work:

```
IRequestClient<ISimpleRequest, ISimpleResponse> client;
var bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
{
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.NotificationServiceQueue, e =>
    {
        e.Consumer(() => new OrderRegisteredConsumer(client));
    });
});

client = new MessageRequestClient<ISimpleRequest, ISimpleResponse>(
    bus, serviceAddress, requestTimeout);
```